# Magento 1.9 Mysql Query to pull out data

Tags: product, database, configurable-product, product-images

I am kind of stuck getting data from magento 1.9.
The solution i needed is mysql query so that I can collect all data in one table.

The values in table i needed from different table are
product id, name, sku, description, price, imagename, image path, meta title, meta description.
I don't know much coding so definite needed mysql query. 
Looking forward a solution from experience developers. Cheers

Comment: all this data can be obtained by doing a product export to csv ... just saying, no need to query anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you an example SQL query to get the product data on basis of `attribute_id`. You can use this as per your requirement.

```
//Product entity type ID
SET @etype = (SELECT 
                    entity_type_id
                FROM
                    eav_entity_type
                WHERE
                    entity_type_code = 'catalog_product');
//Product name attribute ID
SET @name  = (SELECT 
            attribute_id
        FROM
            eav_attribute
        WHERE
            attribute_code = 'name'
                AND entity_type_id = @etype);
//Product image attribute ID
SET @image  = (SELECT 
            attribute_id
        FROM
            eav_attribute
        WHERE
            attribute_code = 'image'
                AND entity_type_id = @etype);
//Product price attribute ID
SET @price  = (SELECT 
            attribute_id
        FROM
            eav_attribute
        WHERE
            attribute_code = 'price'
                AND entity_type_id = @etype);
//Admin store ID
SET @store = 0;

//Query
SELECT 
    e.entity_id AS 'id',
    e.sku,
    v1.value AS 'name',
    v2.value AS 'image',
    si.qty AS 'stock qty',
    d1.value AS 'price'
FROM
    catalog_product_entity e
        LEFT JOIN
    cataloginventory_stock_item si ON e.entity_id = si.product_id
        LEFT JOIN
    catalog_product_entity_varchar v1 ON e.entity_id = v1.entity_id
        AND v1.store_id = @store
        AND v1.attribute_id = @name
        LEFT JOIN
    catalog_product_entity_varchar v2 ON e.entity_id = v2.entity_id
        AND v2.store_id = @store
        AND v2.attribute_id = @image
        LEFT JOIN
    catalog_product_entity_decimal d1 ON e.entity_id = d1.entity_id
        AND d1.store_id = @store
        AND d1.attribute_id = @price;
```

If you know the attribute IDs, you can replace or add the variables in the above query.

**Hope it helps!!!**